# Sharepoint Custom text Web part Property

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

When a user enters custom text in a web part property. It will display on a form.

this is the code for the web part property it is on the the testTextWebPart.ascx.cs

```
public partial class testTextWebPart: WebPart
{
    private string _customtxt;

[WebBrowsable(true),
         Category("Miscellaneous"),
         Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
         WebDisplayName("Enter some text")]
        public string CustomTextProp
        {
            get
            {
                return _customtxt;
            }
            set
            {
                _customtxt = value;
            }
        }
```

I need to display the text onto a form.This page is testTextWebPart.ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function NAME() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var webURL = ctx.get_url;
    var newFormURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + webURL + '/Lists/Testpage/NewForm.aspx';

    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

    options.title = 'PAGE TITLE';
    options.url = newFormURL;

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

I need to display it here. This is in my Control templates folder this page is testText.ascx

```
<div id="divForm" runat="server" style="width:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:10px;">
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;"> DISPLAY HERE </div>
```

I need to get the text the user entere via the webpart properties and then display it on the form when the user clicks the newform.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this method to your code:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    LiteralControl message = new LiteralControl();
    message.Text = CustomTextProp;
    Controls.Add(message);
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a run down on what this does?

Comment: Please go through this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415817(v=office.14).aspx